# How do I remove the annoying underline in flycheck (using eslint)?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs, flycheck

I am using spacemacs and flycheck-eslint as linter to check my React code.

Here is my project's `.eslintrc`,

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
      "jsx": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "semi": [0, "never"],
    "eqeqeq": 2,
    "no-console": 1,
    "no-unused-vars": [1, {"vars": "all", "args": "after-used"}],
    "comma-spacing": [2, {"before": false, "after": true}],
    "react/prop-types": [2, {
      "ignore": ["dispatch"]
    }]
  },
  "globals": {
    "__DEV_MODE__": true,
    "__API_SERVER__": true
  }
}
```

I have set NO semicolon in the `.eslintrc`. I've try Atom Editor, Sublime Text3, VSCode, they work as expect.

But in spacemacs, I got the annoying underline hint.

[image]

How can I remove the annoying underline ??

Thanks!

Comment: By putting in the semi-colon?

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, I can only remove the annoying underline by putting a semicolon... But in my project, semicolon is unnecessary.

Comment: These underlines aren't from Flycheck.  If they were you'd see the yellow dot in the fringe on all the underlines lines.  I presume that's the error highlighting of JS2 Mode.

Comment: @lunaryorn You are right, I've find the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

After researching, I've found that it is not related to flycheck. The underline is added by js2-mode.

The solution is to add `(setq js2-strict-missing-semi-warning nil)` in `.spacemacs` file.

Comment: But I want it to tell me to *remove* semicolons. This just silences the whole thing.

Comment: If you're using flycheck, I think you want `(setq js2-mode-show-strict-warnings nil)`